# Управление памятью в контейнерах

Tags: c++

На чём основано управление памятью в стандартных контейнерных классах (вектор, стек) ? `realloc` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Управление памятью, в стандартным контейнерах, лежит на плечах аллокаторов, если никакой не передаётся, то используется стандартный, который использует `new` и `delete`. Никакого `realloc`. Если не хватает памяти, значит выделяем новую и копируем(перемещаем) всё из старой в новую, а старую удаляем(это поведение вектора, не все контейнеры работают одинаково)

Answer (score 1):

Вектор и стек, вообще говоря, очень разные контейнеры (стек вообще не контейнер, а адаптер над деком). И подходы к управлению памятью у них очень разные.

Впрочем, ни один из стандартных контейнеров не использует `realloc()` (так же как и `malloc()`) по вполне очевидным причинам - `realloc()` ничего не знает о конструкторах.